# Want "null" printed

Tags: jsonpath

Let's say I have this data sample:-

```
{
"store": {
    "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "color": "red", 
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "color": "blue", 
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
        "color": "red",
        "price": 19.95
    }
},
"expensive": 10
```

}

If I look up for the JsonPath $.store..isbn
I get back :-

```
[
  "0-553-21311-3",
  "0-395-19395-8"
]
```

What I want is :-

```
[
  null,
  null,
  "0-553-21311-3",
  "0-395-19395-8"
]
```

Could someone tell if this is possible in JsonPath and if not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compare results length and data length, then push needed amounts of null in the head of array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
But what if the original data had isbn present in the first and third entries unlike here where they are present in the third and fourth column

Comment: As you actually go through books array in fact, I think it is easy just to use map array method and if there no value return null. books.map((book) => { return book.isdn != null? books.isdn : null })

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this with using only JsonPath?

Comment: Aaaa it is Java, I coming from js so not understand at first what is the problem. Can see issue about that - https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/576, so I guess this feature is not in the lib and you have to search other ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Using Configuration you can achieve it.

Need to set `Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL` option in configurations, it will return null if node in not there

Complete example would be:

```
ReadContext ctx=JsonPath.using(Configuration.builder().options(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL).build()).parse(jsonData);
System.out.println(ctx.read("$.store.book..isbn"));
```

**Output:**

`[null,null,"0-553-21311-3","0-395-19395-8"]`